# python json load SortedDict

Tags: python, json, parsing, ordereddict

I have this string

`sorted_dict = '{"state": SortedDict([("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)])}'`

I need to parse

Try:

```
mjl = json.loads(sorted_dict, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict )
```

but I have this error

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 11 (char 10)

Comment: This is not valid JSON. If you wanted to load it with a JSON loader, you should have dumped JSON in the first place. This looks like you probably did something along the lines of `str(some_dict).replace("'", '"')`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid JSON. If you get it like this, and you have no other way to parse it, you could always use `eval`, but keep in mind that **it is risky if you use user input**:

```py
from module import SortedDict

...

mjl = eval(sorted_dict)
```